# How can access to Drawer's mount?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I need to pass a variable to my screens so i did:

```
let x = 10
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Screen1 : {
    screen: (props) => <Screen {...props} x={x} />
  },
  ...
},{
  contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent x={x}/> ,
  ...
})
```

It is working well and pass `x` to all screens and also the drawer content section.
But i need to fetch x from `AsyncStorage` So i need to do this in something like `componentDidMount` of Drawer's self. So How i can do this?

Comment: what if just: https://jsfiddle.net/j0wz8b32/

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks it's working! so i passed a connected ```Socket.io``` client to all my screens. But how it works! this is an async operation!

`let socket
AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(_token=>socket=io(`${Config.SocketURI}/player`,{query:{token : _token}}))`